# Skype 4.3 uses too much bandwidth for the camera

Tags: linux, skype, arch-linux, webcam, bandwidth

On Skype 4.2 everything works perfectly, however when I try to video chat with 4.3, once I turn on the camera it will maximize my upstream until it chokes out everything else and eventually disconnect.

Limiting the upstream prevents the connection from dying, but since it still uses all its allowed bandwidth for sending video, the other person on the line can't hear me at all.

I've had this problem with several kernels, official and custom built and 2 completely different computers (same webcam).

`Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1e4e:0102 Cubeternet GL-UPC822 UVC WebCam [uvcvideo]`

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Bandwidth of what exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound my internet connections. When I turn on my webcam in a chat, skype maximizes my upload stream until the connection dies (monitored with jnetop and gkrellm).

Comment: Have you reported the problem on the Skype forums?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, on both the official 4.3 release post and a post of it's own, which received no answers / comments at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting tired of having to run skype in qemu, I did some digging and ended up using a fake webcam with lower resolution:

```
[Unit]
Description=fake webcam

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/modprobe v4l2loopback card_label='Skype Sucks'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel panic -f v4l2 -video_size 640x360 -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 -vf scale=320:-1 -r 10 /dev/video1
SuccessExitStatus=255
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

gist: https://gist.github.com/OneOfOne/86c444f241a3727fa5046d1fd9323286